# Chrome - Inspect Devices - Select Element is not working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, ionic4, ionic5

To debug a Mobile Application developed using Ionic 5 and Capacitor 2, I use:

```
ionic cap run android -l –external
```

Once the app is loaded in the device, I use Google Chrome and open:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

Under my listed device, I open the **WebView** by clicking **Inspect** link.

This opens the **Chrome DevTools** window. I then enable the *screencast*. And then try to use the *Select an Element* option (Ctrl + Shift + C) to select the HTML element in the **Elements** pane.

**This particular *element selection feature* has stopped working suddenly.** I tried to reinstall chrome completely but it still did not fix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems like it belongs on a [chrome bug list](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) rather than here. Wouldn't you rather the professionals (whom also have access to you application I assume) have a look? Perhaps they will know if the error is not in chrome itself as well.

Comment: I had reported it in the Chrome with all possible supporting data but nobody could identify and fix the issue. And on one fine day, I found the functionality working again!!

Comment: that's classic. I guess time heals all?